# Print Distinct Values from Field AWK

Tags: awk, command-prompt

I'm looking for a way to print the distinct values in a field while in the command-prompt environment using AWK.

```
ID     Title     Promotion_ID     Flag
12     Purse       7               Y
24     Wallet      7               Y
709    iPhone      1117            Y
74     Satchel     7               Y
283    Xbox        84              N
```

Ideally I'd like to return the promotion_ids: 7, 1117, 84. 
I've researched the question on Google and have found some examples such as:

```
`cut -f 3 | uniq *filename.ext*`               (returned error)
`awk cut -f 3| uniq *filename.ext*`            (returned error)
`awk cut -d, -f3 *filename.ext* |sort| uniq`   (returned error)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>1{a[$3]++} END{for(b in a) print b}' file
```

Output:

```
7
84
1117
```

Comment: Awesome work Cyrus, thanks! For any one reading this later on: I had a file that was .txt  tab delimited. For this format, you'll need to tell awk that the file is tab delimited. Code used that was successful: awk -F"\t" "NR>1{a[$4]++} END{for(b in a) print b}" filename.extension

Answer (score 2):

with the pipe line

```
$ sed 1d file    |    # remove header
  tr -s ' ' '\t' |    # normalize space delimiters to tabs
  cut -f3        |    # isolate the field
  sort -nu            # sort numerically and report unique entries

7
84
1117
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Simple `awk` may help.(Following will remove the header of Input_file)

```
awk 'FNR>1 && !a[$3]++{print $3}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you need to keep the Header of the Input_file then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} !a[$3]++{print $3}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@test ~]# cat test
ID     Title     Promotion_ID     Flag
12     Purse       7               Y
24     Wallet      7               Y
709    iPhone      1117            Y
74     Satchel     7               Y
283    Xbox        84              N
```

Output -:

```
[root@test ~]# awk -F" " '!s[$3]++' test
ID     Title     Promotion_ID     Flag
12     Purse       7               Y
709    iPhone      1117            Y
283    Xbox        84              N
[root@test ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mawk '!__[$!NF=$--NF]--^(!_<NR)'  

          or

gawk' !__[$!--NF=$NF]--^(!_<NR)'

          or perhaps

gawk '!__[$!--NF=$NF]++^(NF<NR)' 

          or even

mawk '!__[$!--NF=$NF]++^(NR-!_)'   # mawk-only
gawk '!__[$!--NF=$--NF]--^(NR-NF)' # gawk-equiv of similar idea

7
1117
84
```